# Static type inferring in Ruby, what can I do?

Tags: ruby, types, static, type-inference

I have a school project which aims to statically type some Ruby code. So, my input is simply a **.rb** file, and I should be able to type every variable that is assigned in the program.

Right now, what I'm planning to do is :

- get the file's AST with the Parser library
- put each kind of nodes in container objects
- implement the visitor pattern to recursively go through the program
- try to infer something from there (I was thinking of somehow creating a table of possible input and output types from the core's methods)

I only accept some very basic Ruby as input ( = no call to external library, just the core of ruby + defined-in-the-file methods)

My question is : what do you think of my approach? Is there any gem/existing programs that could help me?

Comment: There's a category of assertions, including "Wrong" and "power_assert", which rip Ruby code into an AST and traverse it looking for values. You could adjust them to look for types too.

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/JetBrains/ruby-type-inference or https://github.com/stereobooster/diamondback-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is *technically* correct, but it sounds very strange how you put it. This:

> Right now, what I'm planning to do is :
>
> - get the file's AST with the Parser library
> - put each kind of nodes in container objects
> - implement the visitor pattern to recursively go through the program
> - try to infer something from there (I was thinking of somehow creating a table of possible input and output types from the core's methods)

sounds a little bit like you wanted to go to Mars like this:

> Right now, what I'm planning to do is :
>
> - get a pencil
> - get a piece of paper
> - get a desk
> - sit down at the desk and use my pen and paper to design a space launch system and Mars lander

In other words, you list three completely trivial points that are maybe an hour of work for an experienced programmer, and then a fourth, that is multiple years of work and worth a PhD.

The most advanced work I know regarding static type inference for Ruby was [*Diamondback Ruby* (DRuby)](http://cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/druby/) (not to be confused with the Distributed Ruby standard library aka dRb / dRuby). However, Diamondback Ruby is now abandoned, since the authors gave up on static type inference for Ruby.

One of the principal researchers behind Diamondback Ruby is now working on a new project called [*RDL*](https://github.com/plum-umd/rdl). The main differences between Diamondback Ruby and RDL are:

- RDL performs dynamic checking, not static checking
- RDL relies on explicit annotations, not implicit inference

[*Steep*](https://github.com/soutaro/steep) is another similar project. It, too, relies on dynamic checking and annotations, and in addition does not actually strive for type-correctness.

[*Ruby Type Inference for IDEA*](https://github.com/JetBrains/ruby-type-inference) is a complete re-think of how JetBrains plans to approach type inference for Ruby in their IDEA / RubyMine IDE. This *does* use type inference, but it uses *dynamic* type inference, not static.

So, as you can see, static type inference for Ruby is so hard that nobody is even trying it, and the guys who *did* try gave up on it and are now doing dynamic type checking with explicit type annotations instead.

[*Ruby Type Checking Roundup* on Robert Mosolgo's blog](http://rmosolgo.github.io/blog/2017/10/06/ruby-type-checking-roundup/) is a good overview about the current state-of-the-art in Ruby typing.

Comment: Hehe now that I indeed made the first steps very fast, I realize that the last one is the non-trivial one! But yeah, before starting, since I've never experimented with this kind of stuff, I was a bit confused. Thanks for the answer! I also programmed a very basic but fully functionnal dynamic program to infer types, and it works with the correct hypothesis.. So i'll use that instead!